# Tuning recommendations from mysqltuner.pl: query_cache_limit

Tags: mysql

The [`mysqltuner.pl`](http://mysqltuner.pl/mysqltuner.pl) script gives me the following recommendation:

```
query_cache_limit (> 1M, or use smaller result sets)
```

And MySQL status output shows:

```
mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Qcache%';
+-------------------------+------------+
| Variable_name           | Value      |
+-------------------------+------------+
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 12264      | 
| Qcache_free_memory      | 1001213144 | 
| Qcache_hits             | 3763384    | 
| Qcache_inserts          | 54632419   | 
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 0          | 
| Qcache_not_cached       | 6656246    | 
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 55280      | 
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 122848     | 
+-------------------------+------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

From the status output above, how can I judge whether or nor the suggested increase in `query_cache_limit` is needed?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your best bet is to set up some kind of test harness that executes a realistic (defined by your scenario) load on your database, and then run that test against MySql with different settings. Tuning is such an art in itself that it is very difficult to give an all embracing answer without knowing your exact needs.

From http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-query-cache.html:

> The `Qcache_free_memory` counter
>   provides insight into the cache's free
>   memory. Low amounts observed vs. total
>   allocated for the cache may indicate
>   an undersized cache, which can be
>   remedied by altering the global
>   variable `query_cache_size`.
>
> `Qcache_hits` and `Qcache_inserts` shows
>   the number of times a query was
>   serviced from the cache and how many
>   queries have been inserted into the
>   cache. Low ratios of hits to inserts
>   indicate little query reuse or a
>   too-low setting of the
>   `query_cache_limit`, which serves to
>   govern the RAM devoted to each
>   individual query cache entry. Large
>   query result sets will require larger
>   settings of this variable.
>
> Another indicator of poor query reuse
>   is an increasing `Qcache_lowmem_prunes`
>   value. This indicates how often MySQL
>   had to remove queries from the cache
>   to make use for incoming statements.
>   Other reasons for an increasing number
>   of `Qcache_lowmem_prunes` are an
>   undersized cache, which can't hold the
>   needed amount of SQL statements and
>   result sets, and memory fragmentation
>   in the cache which may be alleviated
>   by issuing a `FLUSH QUERY CACHE`
>   statement. You can remove all queries
>   from the cache with the `RESET QUERY`
>   `CACHE` command.
>
> The `Qcache_not_cached` counter provides
>   insight into the number of statements
>   executed against MySQL that were not
>   cacheable, due to either being a
>   non-SELECT statement or being
>   explicitly barred from entry with a
>   `SQL_NO_CACHE` hint.

Your hits-to-inserts ratio is something like 1:15 or 6%, so it looks like your settings could do with some finetuning (although, as I said, you are the best judge of that as you know your requirements best).